# JPA entity's collection members get detached or not managed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, openjpa

TGIF guys, but I am still stuck on one of my projects. I have two interfaces `IMasterOrder` and `IOrder`. One `IMasterOrder` may have a Collection of `IOrder`. So there can be several `MasterOrder` entity classes and `Order` entity classes who implements the interfaces.

To simplify the coding, I create `IMasterOrder` and `IOrder` objects everywhere, but when it needs to specify the concrete type then I just cast `IMasterOrder` object to the class type.

The problem is, this makes master class always return null about its orders. I am very curious about how JPA works with polymorphism in general?

## Update

Sorry for the early confusion. Actually the question is much simpler

Actually the entity class is something like this

```
public class MasterOrder implements IMasterOrder {

// Relationships

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "masterOrder")
private OrderCustomFields customFields;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterOrder")
private List<OrderLog> logs;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterOrder")
private Collection<Order> orders;

// Fields...
```

And the finder method to get the Master order entity instance is like this

```
 public static MasterOrder findMasterOrder(String id) {
    if (id == null || id.length() == 0) return null;
    return entityManager().find(MasterOrder.class, id);
}
```

However, the MasterOrder instance from this finder method returns customFields and logs and orders which are all null. So how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think you have to show some code. Specifically when you persist and when you query/use..

Comment: and bear in mind that JPA does not specify support for fields of type interface (or Collection of interface), though some implementations like DataNucleus JPA do provide support for those (vendor extension)

Comment: @barsju thank you for the feedback. I have updated the post then it is very nice of you to give some hints.

Comment: I think you should show the Order class as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access logs and orders, is Master still a part of an active persistence context? ie: Has the EntityManager that found the Master Entity been closed or cleared? If yes, everything is working as expected.

For giggles, you could try changing the fetch attribute on logs and orders to EAGER ... this will help pinpoint if there is something else bad going on.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterOrder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<OrderLog> logs;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterOrder", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Collection<Order> orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with your mapping.. I don't think empty collections should be NULL, they should either be an empty list (if initialized), or a proxy that will be initialized when you read from it. If you leave the transaction and try to read from the collection, it SHOULD throw a lazy initialization exception. In either case, you should include all relevant classes in the question to provide further information.

Comment: Just an FYI, the behavior when accessing an unloaded collection is provider dependent and not all providers will throw a lazy initialization exception.

Comment: I know, but he tagged the question with Hibernate.